# Patch module before importing in Python

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I need to patch a global constant in a module before importing it (before executing code from it).

It's imported as `from app.foo.bar import Bar`.

In the bar (`app/foo/bar.py`) there is a constant I want `mock.patch`, and that constant is checked at load time (code is in the top-level in bar.py). How can I patch constant in `bar.py` before code in `bar.py` check it?

app/foo/bar.py

```py
CONSTANT = 42

if CONSTANT == 42:
  raise Exception("42")
```

I want to change `CONSTANT` to `43` in my code (without changing anything on file system in `bar.py`).

Comment: Just as an alternative idea, could you not do this via environment variables? That would be a lot simpler.

Comment: I do not control the imported code, I can't change there anything. I want to re-export patched code, but I want to do it completely 'in python' without touching files.

Answer (score 0):

your patch would look like this.

```
from app.foo.bar import CONSTANT

CONSTANT=43
```

This would need to be run after app.foo.bar is loaded, so your evaluation would need to be after the fact.

If you want to do it in pytest:

```
def test_CONSTANT(monkeypatch):
    

    monkeypatch.setattr(app.foo.bar,'CONSTANT', 43)
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like what OP asked for. If the value of CONSTANT is checked in `bar`, this will not help.

Comment: the monkey patch in pytest will.

Comment: Don't you still need to perform the import for `app.foo.bar` to be defined?

Comment: Yes, but code edit queue is filled so i can update the answer right now.

Comment: The top block of code won't work, when you do `CONSTANT=43` it'll be assigning to a new variable and won't edit the original one. Also OP is wanting to do this _before_ importing `app.foo.bar` as a heads up.

Comment: It does not fix the problem. When I import something from 'bar', I can change it, but changes are invisible for 'bar' module. (the check in the 'bar.py' is still see it as '42').

Comment: If you need to patch it before import - i think the only way to do it is through an external configuration like an environment variable. If that's not an option - i think you're just "out of luck".